# How to know the possible response when using Android framework's method?

Tags: android, api, android-studio, api-doc

I reference a sample code to practice Android development and some code are as follows:

```
if (response.has("err") && response.optInt("err") != 0) {
    Log.e("error", "There are errors when downloading data.");
}
```

I wonder how to know what the responses may be? E.g. the sample code used "**response.optInt("err") != 0**", which means one possible response is "0", but how can I know other possible responses?

Only can I reference the API docs? Is it possible to show a popup API doc window when mouse hover over on the code, which looks like the JavaDoc on Eclipse?

Comment: You can refer to Android docs or refer to subject whose response you want to check

Comment: Hi @ZaidMirza, could you please give the URL of the API docs? Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/index.html